# Highcharts click events not firing when displaying multiple line series

Tags: highcharts

When I render a line chart with multiple series, the series that has the highest y value for a given data point will trigger the onclick event every time. Every other series will sometimes trigger it, and sometimes not. I can't seem to find any pattern. If I hide a series, the new highest y value will start to work, even if it didn't before.

I'm currently using v6.0.1 of highcharts, but I've recreated the problem in the latest version as well. It also happens on Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

I found a thread on here about click events not firing when showing multiple series, but that was specifically about two series having identical values so that the data points are stacked on top of each other.

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/2opdhxb6/1/.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   "chart":{
      "height":400,
      "type":"areaspline"
   },
   "colors":[
      "#86bbd8",
      "#5e2e94",
      "#c83258",
      "#ffb400",
      "#7bcdba",
      "#ff8300",
      "#4464ad",
      "#e1cba4",
      "#ff9bb8",
      "#808285",
      "#da3ab3",
      "#6ecdb2",
      "#e2cc00",
      "#d8635d",
      "#3b5cad",
      "#9778d3",
      "#00bfd6",
      "#5b2c3f",
      "#4c8b2b",
      "#d9a460"
   ],
   "credits":{
      "enabled":false
   },
   "legend":{
      "borderWidth":"0",
      "symbolRadius":3
   },
   "plotOptions":{
      "series":{
         "cursor":"pointer",
         "fillOpacity":0,
         "lineWidth":2,
         "marker":{
            "enabled":false,
            "lineWidth":1,
            "radius":3,
            "symbol":"circle"
         },
         "point":{
            "events":{
               "click":function () {
                        alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                    }
            }
         },
         "turboThreshold":50000
      },
      "spline":{
         "lineWidth":2,
         "marker":{
            "enabled":true,
            "lineWidth":1,
            "radius":3,
            "symbol":"circle"
         },
         "turboThreshold":50000
      }
   },
   "series":[
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Blog",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"BL",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Blog",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"BL",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":1182
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Blog",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"BL",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":1034
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Blog",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"BL",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":2164
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Blog",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"BL",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":1870
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Blog",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"BL",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":1324
            }
         ],
         "name":"Blog"
      },
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Forum",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"FO",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Forum",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"FO",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":225
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Forum",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"FO",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":239
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Forum",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"FO",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":299
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Forum",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"FO",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":332
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Forum",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"FO",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":181
            }
         ],
         "name":"Forum"
      },
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Online News",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"NM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Online News",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"NM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":4789
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Online News",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"NM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":8495
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Online News",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"NM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":10207
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Online News",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"NM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":5324
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Online News",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"NM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":3383
            }
         ],
         "name":"Online News"
      },
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Print Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"PR",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Print Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"PR",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":542
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Print Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"PR",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":390
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Print Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"PR",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":729
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Print Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"PR",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":713
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Print Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"PR",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":390
            }
         ],
         "name":"Print Media"
      },
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Social Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"SM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Social Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"SM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":113
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Social Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"SM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":94
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Social Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"SM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":79
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Social Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"SM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":99
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Social Media",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"SM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":33
            }
         ],
         "name":"Social Media"
      },
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Radio",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Radio",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":323
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Radio",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":228
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Radio",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":359
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Radio",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":319
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"Radio",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TM",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":180
            }
         ],
         "name":"Radio"
      },
      {
         "data":[
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"TV",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TV",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":0
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"TV",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TV",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":13247
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"TV",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TV",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":14163
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"TV",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TV",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":12370
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"TV",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TV",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":14956
            },
            {
               "Date":null,
               "Medium":null,
               "MediumName":null,
               "SearchName":null,
               "SearchTerm":"TV",
               "Type":"SubMedia",
               "Value":"TV",
               "marker":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "lineWidth":1,
                  "radius":3,
                  "symbol":"circle"
               },
               "name":null,
               "y":6382
            }
         ],
         "name":"TV"
      }
   ],
   "subtitle":{
      "style":{
         "color":"#c4c4c4",
         "fontFamily":"Avenir",
         "fontSize":"12px",
         "fontWeight":null,
         "minWidth":null,
         "textAlign":null,
         "width":null
      },
      "text":"(By Medium)"
   },
   "title":{
      "style":{
         "color":null,
         "fontFamily":"Avenir",
         "fontSize":"20px",
         "fontWeight":"bold",
         "minWidth":null,
         "textAlign":null,
         "width":null
      },
      "text":"Hits"
   },
   "tooltip":{
      "valueSuffix":""
   },
   "xAxis":{
      "categories":[
         "4\/12\/2019",
         "4\/13\/2019",
         "4\/14\/2019",
         "4\/15\/2019",
         "4\/16\/2019",
         "4\/17\/2019"
      ],
      "dateTimeLabelFormats":null,
      "gridLineColor":null,
      "gridLineDashStyle":null,
      "gridLineWidth":null,
      "labels":{
         "enabled":true,
         "formatter":null,
         "rotation":0,
         "staggerLines":0,
         "style":{
            "color":null,
            "fontFamily":"Avenir",
            "fontSize":null,
            "fontWeight":null,
            "minWidth":null,
            "textAlign":null,
            "width":null
         },
         "useHTML":false
      },
      "minorGridLineWidth":null,
      "minorTickInterval":null,
      "plotBands":null,
      "tickInterval":0,
      "tickWidth":2,
      "tickmarkPlacement":"off",
      "title":null,
      "type":null
   },
   "yAxis":[
      {
         "allowDecimals":true,
         "minRange":0.1,
         "title":{
            "margin":10,
            "rotation":270,
            "style":{
               "color":null,
               "fontFamily":"Avenir",
               "fontSize":null,
               "fontWeight":null,
               "minWidth":null,
               "textAlign":null,
               "width":null
            },
            "text":null
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

It's using the actual JSON that I'm rendering in my application, because when I tried sample data I couldn't recreate the issue. I figure I have to have something configured incorrectly, but I have no idea what it could be.

In the example, you can see that all of the data points for the TV series fire the event, but nothing else does. If you hide the TV series, all of the other series except Blog start working. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set chart type equals `areaspline`. That's why series points below the main upper one are hidden beneath it (check it on this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1gs5pb0w/1/). To make it work as expected just change the chart type to `spline`.

Code:

```
   "chart":{
      "height":400,
      "type":"spline"
   }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3q0y1uo/